# Vertex degrees from tree certificate

Tags: graph, theory

Given a tree as a certificate, e.g.

```
00010111
```

how can I compute the degrees of the vertices in the graph WITHOUT reconstructing the tree? Or just find the vertex with max degree?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the solution is rather simple and requires going through the input certificate only once. The pseudocode is as follows:

```
S = new stack of int
max_degree = 0

for i=1 to length( certificate )
 if certificate[i] == 0
   current = S.pop()
   if ( current != null ) 
     current = current +1
     S.push( current )
   S.push( 0 )   
 else
   current = S.pop()
   if ( i != length( certificate ) )
     current = current +1
   if ( current > max_degree )
     max_degree = current
```

The variable max_degree contains the maximal degree of a node in the graph after iterating through the whole certificate